# Mac OS X How to setup App Groups for application and widget

Tags: macos, widget

I have application with a bundle identifier *com.maximbilan.uah-mac* and today extension *com.maximbilan.uah-mac.uah-mac-Today-Extension*.
How to setup App Groups for Mac OS X application?

[image]

I tried to add both identifiers or group name. But validation of archives fails.

[image]

Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should macOS App Group name start with \`group.\` or Development Team ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037745/should-macos-app-group-name-start-with-group-or-development-team-id)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to share data between your application and Today extension?  This should only require one App Group.

Since you are already properly using your `TEAMID`, I think that perhaps hyphens are invalid characters.

Try using 828XSMPA74.com.maximbilan.uah for the App Group name, and then you can create your `NSUserDefaults` object.

```
let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults.init(suiteName: "828XSMPA74.com.maximbilan.uah")!
```