# Should macOS App Group name start with `group.` or Development Team ID?

Tags: macos, entitlements, ios-app-group, appgroups

When I'm trying to upload my app to the Mac App Store, I get the error -

> iTunes Store operation failed.
>
> Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on Mac OS X. Specifically, value '[group.MyCompany.MyProject]' for key 'com.apple.security.application-groups' in 'com.MyCompany.mac.MyProject.pkg/Payload/MyProject.app/Contents/MacOS/MyProject' is not supported. This value should be a string or an array of strings, each starting with your TEAMID followed by a dot '.' .

But I read that the shared group MUST begin with the `group.` prefix - so what is the correct way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, macOS App Groups MUST begin with your **development team ID**.

> The value for this key must be of type array, and must contain one or more string values, each of which must consist of **your development team ID, followed by a period**, followed by an arbitrary name chosen by your development team

Please check below sample from Apple develop page.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW19

```
<key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
<array>
    <string>DG29478A379Q6483R9214.HolstFirstAppSuite</string>
    <string>DG29478A379Q6483R9214.HolstSecondAppSuite</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 3):

`group.identifier` is used for iOS App Group names; `TEAMID` followed by a dot and then name (as the error message states) is used for Mac App Group names.

Also keep in mind that this must be your development team ID; do not use `$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)`, as Xcode suggests.

For some reason the `$(TeamIdentifierPrefix`) build-time variable isn't resolved properly while archiving a project.

Using Jerry's application group name should work.

Answer (score 2):

iOS app groups must be registered in the portal as they need to be whitelisted in provisioning profiles and the portal won't allow you to create app groups that don't start with `group.`

macOS app groups don't have to be registered in the portal at all, they are also not whitelisted in profiles as they are not even present in profiles. If you publish your app on the Mac App Store, though, it will enforce that your app groups must be prefixed by your team ID.

For more details about all this, please see here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66639271/15809